# How to select and deselect checkboxes using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I spent more than an hour to find a satisfying answer or solution to my query but couldn't find one. Although I came across a couple of posts from here but they partially solve my problem.

My issue: I have a form which contains set of checkboxes for three different sections separated by radiobox selection. Here I want to achieve two things:

1. When a user wants to select a section he/she click on the radio button and the respective section should be shown which contains checkboxes inside a DIV.
2. Now, again when user clicks on another radio button I want the checkboxes from the previous section should be unchecked and vice versa.

```
<input type="radio" value="fruit" id="fruit" checked="checked" />Favorite fruit?<br/>
<input type="radio" id="color" value="color" />Favorite color?<br/>
<input type="radio" id="sport" value="sport" />Favorite sport?<br/>

<div id="fruit">
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Apple<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Banana<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Mango<br/>
</div>

<div id="color">
  <input type="checkbox" value="black"> Black<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="orange"> Orange<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="blue"> Blue<br/>
</div>

<div id="sport">
  <input type="checkbox" value="boxing"> Boxing<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="cricket"> Cricketbr/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="football"> Football<br/>
</div>
```

I need to write JavaScript or jQuery code.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: I have searched online but could not find the satisfying answer or solution for my query. Thanks for the support, I will make sure to include all required info if asked.

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique in the entire document, that could be a reason for your code not working as you expect, but you'll have to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many example of what you seek to know. You just need to adapt the code.
I've created a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfnhex47/2/) and I'll try to explain the process.

First of all, you have many items with the same `id`. Id's must be unique.
Second, I've added the attribute `name` since it can come in handy if you're submitting the form.

Then you need to listen for a `change` event on the radio buttons.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="fruit" checked="checked" />Favorite fruit?<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="color" />Favorite color?<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="sport" />Favorite sport?<br />

<div id="fruit">
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Apple<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Banana<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple"> Mango<br />
</div>

<div id="color">
  <input type="checkbox" value="black"> Black<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="orange"> Orange<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="blue"> Blue<br />
</div>

<div id="sport">
  <input type="checkbox" value="boxing"> Boxing<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="cricket"> Cricket<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="football"> Football<br />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
//listen to a change on all radio buttons with the name "choice"
$('input[name="choice"]').on('change', function() {
  var t = $(this); //save this for future reference... this is an optimisation trick if you need to access $(this) many times... in this case it's not necessary.
  $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); //uncheck all checkboxes
  $('div').hide(); //hide all divs
  $('#' + t.val()).show(); //show the correct div which it's id is the same name as the radio's value.

});

$('[name="choice"]:checked').trigger('change'); // trigger the change on the checked item (so we have a visible div on first load).
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, you made my day. I am just starting out with the javascript and had no idea. Many thanks for the great solution and also for useful tips.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. However, just as a heads-up, since the question did not contain any (attempted) JavaScript it is possible it will close as Too Broad, even though this answer was provided. The reasoning for this is that a section of the Stack Overflow community does not want to encourage question authors to ask give-me-the-code questions without demonstrating some effort first (it was not clear from the OP why the code he/she found did not solve the problem).

Comment: The worry is that Stack Overflow is in danger of being known as a place where free labour can be obtained (if that is not already widespread already).